# Javascript FormData function works with Chrome and Opera but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file, jquery-data

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("uploadform"));  
$.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
data.append('file-'+i, file, this.name);                    
});
```

That code works on Chromium 26 but not Firefox 21. I put an alert within the each loop, "alert(this.name)", which displays the filename in Chrome, but nothing in Firefox...so that's apparently where it's all bogging down in Firefox.

I also tried it on Firefox 24--same problem.  I know this code used to work on Firefox--an older version than 21.

This slight change, just leaving off a couple parameters, gives me the same results:

```
var data = new FormData();   
$.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
data.append('file-'+i, file);                   
});
```

I just have no idea what's up, because Mozilla docs show that this is supported and that I'm doing it right.

Here's the ajax call portion of the code if anyone curious (but this is not the problem--it's bogging down in the above code per my alert check):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'upload.php',
data: data,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
cache: false,
type: 'POST',
success: function(data){ }
```

Anyone have any similar problems, or have any inkling where to even look?

Answer (score 0):

Are there errors in your browser's console? Check the Net (or Network) tab as well.

I would test in IE or Opera as well to confirm that it is specifically a FF issue.

Also try producing an alert

```
if (!window.FormData) {
    alert('Doh!');
}
```

Comment: I tried the alert above. It didn't go off in Chromium or Firefox. I only have IE 9 on an old laptop not 10. From what I understand FormData is not supported in IE 9 or less. The only console errors where when the "upload.php" has to read through the already uploaded files -- the error was something to the effect of "corrupt or truncated file" on each of the files that have already been uploaded with Chromium previously. I'll download opera and see what happens with it. I used to have it until I reinstalled debian on my main laptop.

Comment: I just tried it in Opera and it works. So it works in Chromium and Opera, and not in Firefox. (The results are the same on my local LAMP setup and remote LAMP at Linode.com...just in case anyone wondering about servers or anything). Anyone know if anything changed in Firefox lately, because I know my script used to work a few months ago in Firefox. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just tried Iceweasel (Firefox 10) on Debian and same problem as Firefox 21 and Firefox 24 -- doesn't work. I could've sworn that the files script used to work in Firefox. I have no idea.

Comment: @JeffAgee There's a problem with your code. Have you been able to get it working?